# search_path set and seen but not used!

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, psql

Even though I'm (apparently) setting the search_path correctly I still have to prefix everything with the schema. What's wrong here?  How do I get a default schema from the *search_path*?

```
psql blip
psql (9.4.1, server 9.4.4)
Type "help" for help.

blip=> \dt messages

no matching relations found.
blip=> \dt blip_schema.messages
            List of relations
   Schema    |   Name   | Type  | Owner  
-------------+----------+-------+--------
 blip_schema | messages | table | dbuser
(1 row)
blip=> set search_path to "blip_schema,public";
SET
blip=> show search_path;
     search_path      
----------------------
 "blip_schema,public"
(1 row)

blip=> \dt messages
No matching relations found.
blip=> \dt blip_schema.messages
            List of relations
   Schema    |   Name   | Type  | Owner  
-------------+----------+-------+--------
 blip_schema | messages | table | dbuser
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double quotes denote identifiers that contain special characters, so `set search_path to "blip_schema,public"` will set the search path to a **single** schema named `blip_schema,public`.

The names you supply to `set search_path` have to follow regular naming rules, so no quotes at all, unless you have one schema that requires quoting:

```
set search_path to blip_schema,public;
```

or if you do want to use quotes, you need them for *each* identifier:

```
set search_path to "blip_schema","public";
```

Comment: Yes, I dropped the quotes and it worked.  I put them in out of habit from working with protocols, such as _CSS_ that require them for parameter lists.  So _postgresql_ takes a search_path that refers to no real schemas without comment and, if you (mistakenly) think that the quote marks are correct, makes it look as if it actually **is** referring to real schemas.

Comment: @Nadreck: yes, because invalid schemas in the search_path are silently ignored. See the manual for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH